# Rails Fullcalendar modal close gets uncaught error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have a Rails app using Fullcalendar.  It has a modal for entering labor hours.  The modal shows up fine and if you enter data, it gets added to the database.

But, the modal won't close.  Even the Cancel button and the X in the top right corner of the modal don't work.

I get an `Uncaught jQuery.event.remove` in the browser Console.  See attached pic.

I have very similar code working in another application.  I've looked and looked for differences that would cause this - to no avail.

The statement not working is `$(this).dialog "close"`.  But, like I said, that statement works fine in another application using Fullcalendar.

I'm just not sure where to look.

How do I chase down the uncaught error?
(I feel like it some other javascript (not Fullcalendar) that's causing the error.)

Here is the coffeescript where the buttons are created:

```
   $("#dialog-form").dialog
     autoOpen: true
     height: 450
     width: 400
     modal: true
     buttons:
      "Create Labor": ->
        $.create "/events/",
          event:
            workorder_id: workorder.val(),
            actcode_id: actcode.val(),
            title: title.val(),
            description: description.val(),
            hours: hours.val(),
            starts_at: "" + start,
            ends_at: "" + end,
            all_day: allDay,
            maxsynch: "N",
            employee_id: $('#calendar').data('employeeid'),
            overtime: "TRUE" if $("#overtime").is(":checked")
          complete: ->
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
        $(this).dialog "close"
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
        $("#workorder_id").val("")
        $("#title").val("")
        $("#hours").val("")
        $("#description").val("")
      Cancel: ->
        $(this).dialog "close"
```

This is a screenshot:

[image] 
Thanks for the help!

UDPATE

With the dialog displaying, I typed the following into the browser console:

```
$(this).dialog("close")
```

And got this message:

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

And the following did nothing:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog("close")
```

UPDATE2

This worked to close the modal:

```
$('.ui-dialog').remove()
```

But, the page is left grey and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - kind of.

I switched from `gem bootstrap-sass` to `gem twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

The problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in `$(this).dialog "close"` is probably not pointing to the modal, but to the button.

What is you change this line to:

```
$('#modalId').dialog "close"
```

(replace `modalId` with the id you have)

Comment: I've tried this: `$('#dialog-form').dialog('close')` get the same error.

Comment: And this `$('#dialog-form').dialog "close"`

Comment: This same dialog close code is closing the dialog box in the previous version of the application.  I'm having trouble seeing how any other code could interfere with this dialog close.